# Dynamically pass keys to map to new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Sorry for the confusing title, wasn't sure how to describe this in a one liner.

I have the following utility function:

`module.exports.reduceObject = item => (({ price, suggested_price }) => ({ price, suggested_price }))(item);`

Which takes the `values` from the keys `price` and `suggest_price` and returns a new object with just those keys and values.

I can then turn an object like this:

```
inspect_link: 'steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198279893060A%item_id%D9567622191659726240',
price: '2.15',
suggested_price: '2.90',
is_featured: false,
float_value: '-1.00000',
pattern_info: 
 { paintindex: 0,
   paintseed: null,
   rarity: 3,
   quality: 4,
   paintwear: null },
is_mine: false,
tags: { type: 'Collectible', quality: 'Normal', rarity: 'High Grade' },
fraud_warnings: [],
stickers: null,
updated_at: 1501880427 }
```

Into it's reduced version:

```
{"price":"2.59","suggested_price":"1.41"}
```

Which I'm then storing in a MongoDB database.

I'd like to be able to pass in the keys (such as `price`, `suggested_price` dynamically so I can reduce any object to a smaller version of itself, but I'm struggling to find a good implementation.

I wrote something such as:

```
module.exports.reduceObject = (item, keys) => (({ ...keys }) => ({ ...keys }))(item);
```

which isn't valid, but I honestly have no idea how to even approach this.

Can anybody offer a solution?

Comment: Object spread is not available in Node.js unless you use babel.

Comment: @Dez balls. I wonder why VSCode hasn't picked up on that.

Comment: About VSCode not checking that check this piece of documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_disable-syntax-validation-when-using-non-es6-constructs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find lodash's implementation hard to read. If you're like me, here's a simpler implementation:

```
function pick(object, keys) {
    const result = {};
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = object[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Depending on your use, it can be important to check whether the key is actually in the source object. This has slipped me up before.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a powerful lodash library which does what you need. It has `pick` function which returns an object composed of the picked object properties:

```
let newItem = _.pick(item, ['price', 'suggested_price']);
```

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from third party packages but I'm having a read through the source for `_.pick` now, thanks!

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it led me to the right conclusion, but I've gone with a native implementation found here: https://github.com/tlvince/es6-pick/blob/master/index.js Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: Glad that my answer sent you in the right direction. But my advice to you - don't create a bicycle, when already exists much more powerful and elegant solution. The such library as lodash has a lot of helpful functions.

Comment: It's more I'm choosing not to get an electric bike just because it's 2017. I don't want to use third party libraries for a few reasons, but the source code for `pick` has helped. Thanks again.